# How long would it take to build an artificial island above the Kerguelen Plateau?

Tags: geography, ocean, topography

Without thinking about the costs, how long would it take to build an artificial island the size of New Zealand on the shallow waters above the Kerguelen Plateau? This means using one million boats using today's technology by extracting sand and rock from the sahara and antarctica respectively.

Comment: It would depend on how you build it.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to specify the means --- what kinds of technology are available and how much? The less you specify in your question, the lower the quality and the greater the variance in the answers.

Comment: "Without thinking about the costs" - does it we we can commandeer resources of the entire human civilization for this project?

Comment: Can you construct a series of coffer dams and drain the water? Or does the land need to be at sea level?

Comment: Just a few 100,000 years, zero dollars.. wait for the vulcano.. it will do all the work :d

Comment: The edit is problematic because it invalidates your existing answer. It would still be closed as lacking details and clarity unless you are specific about the available technology in 2040-50.

Comment: this could be a decent question with better constraints, saying regardless of cost actually makes it more problematic.  what the end goal of construction is is important, a dead pile of sand is different than something you want people to live on.

Answer (score 1):

**One Thousand Years**

Some rough numbers:

Area of New Zealand -- 250,000 sq.km

Area of Palm Jumeirah -- 6 sq.km

[image]

Time to build the palm -- 5 years

**Time to build New New Zealand -- 200,000 years**

Of course this assumes we use the same number of boats for each. Maybe we can use more boats for NNZ since there is more space than for the palm. Let's say we scale up the operation and have 41,000 as many boats (whew). Then it is a matter of how deep we have to go to dredge up material.

Some more rough numbers:

Depth of the palm (continental shelf depth) -- 300 metres

Depth of the Plateau -- 3,000 metres

Since the island is ten times as high it needs ten times the material.

**Time to build New New Zealand -- 50 years**

Again this assumes the same methods work. The palm is build from dredging sand from the bottom of the continental shelf, or from even shallower areas. We cannot expect the same materials to be available from the ocean floor. And we cannot expect to harvest those materials at the same speed.

I will pull a number from the air and say the different methods are 20 times less efficient. This gives 1000 years.

Comment: Where do you get 300 meters as the depth is built in? The Persian Gulf itself has a maximum depth of 90 meters, and the deepest water the Palm was built in was only 10 meters. That put you off by a factor of 30.

Comment: You could try Newer Zealand and hope that you get the same customer a maximum of once more.

Comment: @KeithMorrison I just took the continental shelf depth. You are probably right it is too big. Wow, what a good answer to encourage discussion!

Comment: don't forget Kerguelen Plateau is much further from the source material and in open water, so that will drastically slow operations.